# How should a constructor report errors? Pointers to external flags?

Tags: c++, class, reference

I am working on refactoring some of the old C-style code to bring it more into line with C++ code. I still am a bit new to C++

An example of the code I am working on is as follows

```
Errmsg foo{
   ErrMsg err = NoError;
   /*
    Some Processing
   */
  err = foo_cleanup(err,/* some parameters*/);
   /*
    Some More Processing
   */
  return err;
}
```

I was thinking of developing a class so that

```
class foo_class
{
 public:
   foo_class(Errmsg errmsg_init&,/*Some other arguments */ ):
      errmsg(&errmsg_init),
      /*Initialize other parameters */{}

   void foo_cleanup (/*Other parameters*/);
   // same functionality, but since the source variable is available, 
   // it can be modified without having to return any variable

  ~foo_class(){foo_cleanup(/*Parameters*/);}

   /*
   Member functions
   */

 private:
   Errmsg* errmsg;
   /*Some other parameters */
};

Errmsg foo{
   ErrMsg err = NoError; 
   foo_class foo_obj(err);
   /*
    Some Processing
   */

  // The class would be 
  //cleaned up before returning 
  // and the err variable would be 
  //modified in the destructor
  return err;
}
```

Although I have been able to use something similar to this approach, I do not know if this will be portable.

Is this the right thing to do?

If not, do I just use pointers to initialize the class instead of passing the error message variable by reference? Or is there something else I can do?

I cannot use exceptions at the current stage because there are many function calls to/from external code which use a "return error message" approach still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside that you should if possible fix the calling code so that an exception is OK, you could use the two-phase construction idiom:

```
struct foo_class {
    foo_class() { } // default constructor cannot fail
    Errmsg nothrow_init(/* other params */) throw() {
        /* initialize other parameters */
    }
    foo_class(/* other params */) {
        if (nothrow_init(/* other params */) != ERRMSG_OK) {
            throw something;
        }
    }
};
```

Now, exception-using code can call the multi-arg constructor (and get the object in a ready-to-use state), whereas exception-averse code can call the default constructor followed by `nothrow_init` (and live with the fact that if `nothrow_init` fails they have an unusable object on their hands, and it's their responsibility to ensure that they don't use it).

In future, as you bring other parts of your code base into an exception-using state, you will find that the code in `init` calls things that can themselves throw. At that point you can start moving code around, so that the `nothrow_init` calls an `init` function that can throw, but catches any exceptions and turns them into error codes. Assuming it's an internal class then eventually nothing will be using `nothrow_init` and you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is dangerous because it permits bad use-cases such as this:

```
return new FooClass (local_error_code_variable);
```

Don't try to signal constructor failures with return codes. *You can't.* Use exceptions.

You can wrap exceptions in return codes and vice-versa.

```
class NewAPIClass {
    NewAPIClass () {
        error_code err = old_api_function ();
        if (OLD_API_OK != err)
            throw NewAPIException (err);
    }
}

extern "C" error_code new_api_callback_function (argument arg) {
    try {
        NewAPIClass object;
        object .do_work ();
    }
    catch (...) {
        return OLD_API_ERROR;
    }
}

int main () {
    old_api_install_callback (new_api_callback_function);
}
```

Exceptions are important. There are lots of good [GOTW articles](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) and you should make understanding them a goal in being a C++ developer.

Write the new code to use exceptions properly. Convert error types whenever you hit a boundry between old and new code.

By the way, exceptions are the ***only*** reasonable way for a constructor to fail. It's all part of RAII which is a key to making C++ so powerful. Constructors establish your invariants and exceptions signal a failure to satisfy postconditions -- put it all together and here is the important philosophy: ***in C++ only valid objects should exist***, if you get this right by exploiting RAII then the continued existence of an object is proof of the program's validity.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use exceptions at the current stage because there are many
>   function calls to/from external code which use a "return error
>   message" approach still.

Then fix that problem first. Then use exceptions.

Comment: -1 because... so many things. Exceptions are a tool. Saying disregard everything and hammer your beliefs how you should program are another one. One sentence replies are rarely useful. Exceptions as control flow?? etc.. etc... Please expand your reasoning and I'll vote it up and say I was wrong.

Comment: See my answer and the linked GOTW. Exceptions are not suitable for every situation, but for those situations which they are, there are ***NO*** valid alternatives. Failed object construction is one of those.

Comment: How about NOT doing things in the constructor for which flow control is more suited. Sometimes is perfectly valid to do these kind of things there. This is clearly here not the case. Really, you people would throw CHeyWeJustAddedANumberException if you had the chance :P

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I did not advocate exceptions as control flow or demonstrate any other OTT advocation of exceptions. Exceptions are, however, great for signalling errors and vastly better than return codes, and *should* be used instead.